# Is there a const function in C?

Tags: c, function, constants

I mean can we declare a function in C as const like

```
void fun(int iVar) const;

int g_var = 1;

void fun(int iVar)
{
  //do some thing
  g_var = iVar;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it, or check the documentation, before asking? And what do you expect `const` to do there? That isn't legal or meaningful in C++, either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not in standard C, since there are no classes or objects (as in "class instances, i.e. collections of data with associated functions"), there's nothing for the function to be `const` "against".

There could in theory be such a notation to mean "this function has no globally visible side-effects, it's a pure function of its input arguments" but there isn't.

The GNU GCC compiler supports, [as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), declaring a function as either `const` or `pure`:

```
int square(int) __attribute__((pure));
```

The `__attribute((pure))` part is GCC-specific.

Comment: `since there are no classes or objects` It depends on what you mean by objects. C does have *objects*.

Comment: Note that the function in OP is not pure, by any means.

Comment: what does "__attribute((pure))" mean? Does it brings const behaviour to the function?

Comment: @user2706540 You could look it up and find out.

Comment: @KingsIndian In context "...classes or objects...", how does C have objects? Do you just mean putting function pointers as members of structs? If so, that doesn't make C language have objects (or, by extension, object related keywords), any more than being able to implement matrices with C structs makes C have matrices.

Comment: @hyde: An "object" in C is a "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values" (C11 3.15.1). They're not the same thing as OOP objects, I suspect KingsIndian was making the point that OOP doesn't have a monopoly over this term.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thanks for the standard reference. Indeed object has many many meanings, and interestingly it looks like C++ standard also uses the word in much the same meaning as C standard (plus some details about stuff like polymorphism), which is wider than the OOP meaning of the word.